# PHP Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/co

Tags: php, wordpress

I need code to avoid this error in this part:-
added to woocommerce product edit page option to select specific user/s or specific user role/s or specific group/s the selected users will find in specific front end page a select box to choose product

the only way to work without showing the error is ( I must select at least one user and one user role and one group) 
if I left even if one field of the three fields empty then once the selected user visit the front end page  I got the next error in error_log

> [09-Apr-2020 15:55:52 UTC] PHP Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2
>   to be array, null given in
>   /home/comenzo/mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php on
>   line 1128

also I get Notice in line 1128

> Undefined offset: 0

this is line 1128

```
if(in_array($user_id,get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list")[0]) || in_array($user_roles[0],get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_role_list")[0]) || in_array($group_id,get_post_meta($product_id,"product_point_groups")[0])) {
```

the whole code of this part is

```
echo "<label>Select Product</label>";
echo '<select class="user_product" name="user_product" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:30px;margin-top:30px;" required>';
echo "<option value='-1'>Select Product</option>";
/*echo "<h1>HEllo JMM JMK JPD!</h1>";*/
foreach($product_ids as $product_id)
  { 
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    /*echo "<h1>HEllo JMM JMK JPD!</h1>";
    print_r(get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list"));
    print_r(get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_role_list"));
    print_r(get_post_meta($product_id,"product_point_groups"));*/
    if(in_array($user_id,get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list")[0]) || in_array($user_roles[0],get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_role_list")[0]) || in_array($group_id,get_post_meta($product_id,"product_point_groups")[0])) {
        echo "<h1>IN</h1>";
    ?>
```

so please need code to avoid this error 
need if I select only one field or tow from the three fields to not get this error or even if I don't select any of them

regards

Comment: If `get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list")` returns a list of the data, then using `[0]` will mean this item is now just the first item of the list.

Comment: so suppose to be what would you please write the right code

Comment: As Nigel Ren suggests, try removing [0] from the 2nd parameter. But first uncomment your print_r lines and check if each post meta is an array.

Comment: I found the reason , I must select at least one user and one user role and one group in each product edit page to avoid appearing of this error if one of them is left blank then it will give the error now I need code to tell what to do when one of these fields is blank so would you please provide one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you using the `[0]` but if the actual meta value is supposed to be an array, then this would work:

```
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

$product_user_list = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list");
$product_user_role_list = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_role_list");
$product_point_groups = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_point_groups");

$product_user_list_array = is_array( $product_user_list ) ? $product_user_list : array();
$product_user_role_list_array = is_array( $product_user_role_list ) ? $product_user_role_list : array();
$product_point_groups_array = is_array( $product_point_groups ) ? $product_point_groups : array();

if( in_array($user_id, $product_user_list_array) || in_array($user_roles[0],$product_user_role_list_array) || in_array($group_id,$product_point_groups_array)) {
    echo "<h1>IN</h1>";
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code I removed also [0]  and I got the next results  1- the php error disappeared     2- only user role worked and user and group stopped I meant if in product A I selected user1  and I selected group1 (user1 belong to it)  and user1 visit frontend page then will not find the product  (that is not right)  but if I selected user role (customer) where user1 is customer then he find the product in the selectbox in the front end  so please how to let user/s and group works

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds like a whole different set of codes that needs to be working together to achieve what you want, I can't help you with that.

Comment: dear Ali I just added [0] to your code only in 2 lines     $product_user_list = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_list")[0];
        $product_user_role_list = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_user_role_list");
        $product_point_groups = get_post_meta($product_id,"product_point_groups")[0];      now the error is gone and the product appear in the list in front end only I have 2 Notices saying Undefined offset: 0 in line 1125 and 1127  the 2 lines that I add to it [0]  so we are near I thing what do you recommend to fix this notices